# Openlayers v4.0.1 support Google Maps Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, google-maps, google-maps-api

I want to know if the latest version of Openlayers (v4.0.1) supports Google Maps as a Tile Layer. I can't find any document ion about this. If Openlayers doesn't support Google Maps, could someone  tell me if there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 25):

I can use Google Maps in OpenLayers 4.2 like this under my WMS layer and its perfectly fitted with EPSG:3857 projection:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://khm{0-3}.googleapis.com/kh?v=742&hl=pl&&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' })})
```

Why do you need a plugin?

Youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkSpdE8HNxc)

JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/omurbilgili/eyytw0gc/4/)

for ROADMAP

```
new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@113&hl=en&&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' })})
```

If you face the fitted problem with EPSG:3857 projection when you use Geoserver or other vector sources; use like this

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
        'title': 'Google Maps Uydu',
        'type': 'base',
         visible: true,
        'opacity': 1.000000,
         source: new ol.source.XYZ({
         attributions: [new ol.Attribution({ html: '<a href=""></a>' })],
         url: 'http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga'
         })
}),
```

Comment: Awesome! After googling the entire first half of the day, this is the best solution that saved me a lot of work! :)

Comment: This shows satellite view, how can I show the default view that loads on google map?

Comment: @BiJ default view? roadmap or hybrid? I added roadmap view tile define this answer.

Comment: Hi, it's not working anymore (404) do you have a workaround?

Comment: @AlexandreMélard I think Google close this source, I am sorry, but can you try this? http://mapgears.github.io/ol3-google-maps/examples/

Comment: I'll check it out, let you know if it's working

Comment: Hi @AlexandreMélard I updated this code sample and its work perfectly, https://jsfiddle.net/omurbilgili/eyytw0gc/569/

Comment: @ÖmürBilgili Thanks a lot... awesome solution!!. Would like to know is there any option to add my Google Map API's license/Key here?

Comment: This is against Google Maps terms of service. DO NOT DO THIS! https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms section e- No Use With Non-Google Maps, and: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/9900#issuecomment-527464084

Comment: @Eoin https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-dev/2012-April/008625.html "you should consider this email the "written consent" that you need from us to continue using the Google Maps APIs in OpenLayers" this is old though, I wonder if they still offer consent. It probably still requires the use of an account key.

Comment: @ADJenks Yes, it used to be legal for OpenLayers version 2 to do this using a built-in Openlayers layer. However, Google's terms have changed. https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/9900#issuecomment-741965058

Comment: @Eoin Ah yes, maybe someone should ask permission for a specific exception again :)

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to us ol.source.Tile to access to every google maps. For everybody needs it, this is the basic code to create every available google maps layer to add to a map developed in Openlayers 4:

```
var googleLayerRoadNames=new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "Google Road Names",
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
});

var googleLayerRoadmap=new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "Google Road Map",
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
});

var googleLayerSatellite =new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "Google Satellite",
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=pl&&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
});

var googleLayerHybrid =new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "Google Satellite & Roads",
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
});

var googleLayerTerrain =new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "Google Terrain",
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=t&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
});

var googleLayerHybrid2 =new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "Google Terrain & Roads",
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
}); 

var googleLayerOnlyRoad=new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "Google Road without Building",
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
});
```

Comment: Be careful if you plan to use this; it is a direct violation of Google Maps' terms of service and you will likely get in trouble.

Comment: what about traffic layer

Comment: According to this page http://blinktag.com/google-transit-layer-through-google-maps-api/ 
for traffic layer you may use this url: http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@155076273,transit:comp|vm:&hl=en&opts=r&s=Galil&...
But, as noted by Alex McMillan, using google maps inside a not google library is a violation of term of service.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-dev/2012-April/008625.html "you should consider this email the "written consent" that you need from us to continue using the Google Maps APIs in OpenLayers" this is old though, I wonder if they still offer consent. It probably still requires the use of an account key.

Comment: @ADJenks The last entry of your link actually suggests there is **NO LONGER** consent from Google: *"I'm afraid the comments in the blog post and 10.2 (a) in the TOS make it quite clear that it is not permitted to wrap the Google Maps API in another mapping API like OpenLayers."* - https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-dev/2012-April/008625.html

Comment: Thank you for catching that @MatthewSpence. <Insert some sort of quote about giving and taking away.>

Answer (score 5):

No it doesn't, and it will probably never support it, since there is no direct tiles access with GMaps. The only option that I know of is still something like: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps

Comment: I could not get, what is the issue here, Ömür Bilgili already gave the sample code which works fine.

Comment: It works but it's a violation of their terms of service.

Answer (score 3):

I have already given an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42616386/6068293
could you please comment if that is what you are looking for?

Creating a solution for the plain map data would need to combine the understanding of the data downloaded by such requests:
https://www.google.pl/maps/vt/stream/pb=!1m7!8m6!1m3!1i11!2i348!3i816!2i4!3x65535!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i375060690!2m38!1e2!2sspotlight!4m2!1sgid!2sXMf6EbH1C4DOnd6foX0POg!8m32!1m2!12m1!20e1!2m8!1s0x80c2c75ddc27da13%3A0xe22fdf6f254608f4!2sLos+Angeles%2C+Kalifornia%2C+Stany+Zjednoczone!4m2!3d34.0522342!4d-118.24368489999999!5e1!6b1!9e0!11e1!13m10!2shplexp%2Ca!15b1!18m3!5b0!6b0!8b0!22m3!6e2!7e3!8e2!19u6!19u7!19u11!19u12!19u14!19u20!20m1!1e6!3m8!2spl!3spl!5e1105!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!4e1!6m6!1e12!2i2!28e3!39b1!44e2!50e0&authuser=0

The creation of data in the memory of the browser:
https://superuser.com/questions/948738/what-is-the-blobhttp-prefix-and-where-can-i-learn-more-about-this
and retrieving tiles from BLOB data put in the browser

Comment: One more thought on the subject. Tiles are available under a following addresses: http://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i6!2i34!3i20!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i375060738!3m9!2spl!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0 which have been utilized by a previous version of OpenLayers and GoogleMaps API itself. The only problem is to find out the meaning of the pb parameter...

Comment: I still don't know the whole pb argument, but X, Y and ZOOM of the tile are placed as marked below:
!1m5!1m4!1i{ZOOM}!2i{X}!3i{Y}!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i3175062737!3m9!2spl!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0

Comment: I doubt this is a legal approach

Comment: I haven't been aware, but @bartvde is right: [No access to APIs or Content except through the Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to include google maps to openlayers. You can copy my code. (TypeScript)

```
import {Layer} from './../abstract-layer';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
```

declare var ol: any;
declare var window: any;

@Injectable()
export class GoogleLayers extends Layer {
    private layers = [];
    private language = 'en';
    private country = 'US';

`` constructor() {
    super();
    var me = this;
    let layerRoad = new ol.layer.Tile({
        visible: false,
        preload: Infinity,
        source: new ol.source.TileImage({
            wrapX: true,
            maxZoom: 19,
            url: `http://maps.google.de/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i{z}!2i{x}!3i{y}!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i375060738!3m9!2s${this.language}!3s${this.country.toUpperCase()}!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0`

        })
    });
    layerRoad.displayName = 'Google Maps Road';
    let layerSatelliet = new ol.layer.Tile({
        visible: false,
        preload: Infinity,
        source: new ol.source.TileImage({
            maxZoom: 19,
            wrapX: true,
            url: `https://www.google.de/maps/vt/pb=!1m5!1m4!1i{z}!2i{x}!3i{y}!4i256!2m2!1e1!3i762!3m9!2s${this.language}!3s${this.country.toUpperCase()}!5e1105!12m1!1e4!12m1!1e47!12m1!1e3!4e0!5m1!1e0`

        })
    });
    layerSatelliet.displayName = 'Google Maps Satellit';

    this.layers.push(layerRoad);
    this.layers.push(layerSatelliet);
}

getLayers() {
    return this.layers;
}
} ``

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Openlayers has stopped supporting Google maps from version 3 onwards. Try to use leaflet instead of Openlayers. Which is light weight and has most of the features of Openlayers. If anything is missing you can easily add it as a plugin.Adding Google Maps using ol.layer.Tile is against Google license agreements.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting - this answer is correct.