# Is there a 3rd-party Google Maps API for OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers, google-maps, google-maps-api

Recently, I immigrated to the OpenLayers 4 and I've just wondered if there is any 3rd-party or plugins in order to add Google Maps layers such as Satellite, Hybrid and etc in my project. How should I achieve this?

Why isn't it support anymore?

**Edit:**

I see the below link in `StackExchange`. Someone says that we can use `leaflet` instead of OpenLayers, which isn't my goal and someone else introduced the `ol3-google-maps` plugin which integrated Google Maps into the OL3. but it's named `OL3` and I confused about it. Can I use it with OpenLayers 4 and is it compatible well?

[Openlayers v4.0.1 support Google Maps Javascript API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231629/openlayers-v4-0-1-support-google-maps-javascript-api)

Comment: Why do you need a plugin? Do you want to use google maps only basemap?

Comment: @ÖmürBilgili Hi, I should migrate to the new OL (OpenLayers 4) and unfortunately there isn't support for the Google layers in the new OL anymore. My current project has been written by OL2. Anyway, I'd like to add the Google Sattelite and Hybrid layer as the base layer with OL 4 based application.

Comment: Ok, I get it, I worked on same situations, Our project migrated Ol2 to Ol4. I solved like this. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/253183/103570

Comment: @ÖmürBilgili. Your answer has been very helpful. Thanks! I will give it a try.